# Converting putty private key to openssh format causing Invalid key length failure

Tags: linux, putty, openssh, ssh-keys

I've a putty generated keypair file from which I try to save the private key in openssh format with:

```
puttygen -O private-openssh privat.ppk -o privat.pem
```

But when I try to use the private key for openssh publickey auth I always get the

```
debug1: load_identity_file: Skipping key /home/gerijani/.ssh/id_rsa: Invalid key length
```

I've tried to convert it with the windows GUI version into new openssh or ssh.com format. I've tried to convert with cli on Fedora system as well, but the same result. I've also tried to convert the existing RSA key to OPENSSH format with:

```
ssh-keygen -p -N "" -f priv_new.pem
```

Meanwhile if I try to login to the target node with putty, login is always successful.

Comment: What _is_ the 'size' (bits in modulus) of your key? If you are using very recent OpenSSH (>=9.1) check if it is configured (in ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/ssh_config or similar, or with a wrapping script or alias) to have option RequiredRSASize (in any case, but that's canonical) set too high for your key.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  
I use openssh 8.8p1 without RA keysize restriction and according to :  
```openssl rsa -in privat.pem -text -noout 
'Private-Key: (2047 bit, 2 primes)```  
But I don't get it why it is working with putty - on Win10 and on Fedora- and not with openssh client

Comment: I don't understand either; 2047 bit should be valid. Assuming `id_rsa` is the same as `privat.pem` -- did you confirm that?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yes. In fact, I've tried to specify it with 'ssh -i' as well. Odd is, if I generate a new key on my Fedora and copy the new public key to the target it works.
But I guess, I confirmed it's an ssh client issue on Fedora as I've tried it from another laptop with Wim10 and MobaXterm IT WORKS. I also tried it from a CoreELEC Linux box 
CoreELEC:~ # ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.2p1, OpenSSL 3.0.8 7 Feb 2023
and work from there as well. But I still don't know what could be the problem with 8.8.p1 as I 'm using with default config.

Comment: Gack! I didn't notice Fedora! Is your putty from the Fedora packagers or elsewhere? RHEL 8 up and Fedora I-don't-know-exactly-which have _systemwide_ crypto policies that apply to most if not all distro packages and [it appears now rejects RSA<2048 by default](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/StrongCryptoSettings2). If you run `openssl genrsa 2047` does it generate a key and does that key work in OpenSSH?

Comment: It's working. Generates a private key without error. I'm just curious, it generates a key which begins with -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY------ while the one which was converted from putty key begins with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY------
And if I pipe the new key to file it's 1700byte while the converted is 1663

Comment: You're using OpenSSL 3.0.0 up? That writes PKCS8 format (BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY or ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY) while older writes 'traditional' PKCS1 format (RSA PRIVATE KEY) which is slightly smaller, but length is also affected by setting a password and some random factors. OpenSSH should read either, as well as (>=6.5) its own 'new' format (OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY). My question was: does `openssl genrsa 2047` create a key _AND_ does (Fedora) `ssh` _accept THAT (2047-bit) key_?

Comment: Yes and yes. So, it's openssl 3.0.9 and ssh accept it without hesitation.

Comment: Okay, if a 2047-bit key generated by `openssl` works but one converted by `puttygen` doesn't, I give up. There is nothing that should be different between those.